# SQL Field Length

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT @list = (seg_tag+
                '01'+ 
                CAST(LEN(ID_Type) AS NVARCHAR)+
                ID_Type+
                '02'+
                CAST(LEN(IDNumber) AS NVARCHAR)+
                IDNumber)
FROM #TEMP_TABLE_ID
```

In the above query, What do I need to do so that when I print the list,The length (in case its a single digit) comes out with a zero?
Ex.

```
04 for 4
09 for 9
14 for 14
```

Sample data in #TEMP_TABLE_ID:

```
seg_tag | ID_Type | IDNumber
--------+---------+----------
PN03    | paras   | narang
```

And result should looks like this: `PN03015paras026narang`

Comment: Please add some sample data of your `#TEMP_TABLE_ID` and your final expected results ;).

Comment: Here it is,My original query will return a string like PN03015paras026narang PN03(i.e value of seg_tag)01(hard coded)5(length of id_type)paras(value of id_type)02(hard code)6(length of IDNumber)narang(value of IDNumber) Now all I want is, the lengths i.e 5 & 6 to be 05 and 06.

Comment: Have you tried using `Right( '00' + Cast( 5 as NVarChar(2) ), 2 )`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need just this:

```
SELECT @list = seg_tag 
             + '01' + RIGHT('0' + CAST(LEN(ID_Type) AS varchar), 2) 
             + ID_Type  
             + '02' + RIGHT('0' + CAST(LEN(IDNumber) AS varchar), 2)
             + IDNumber
FROM #TEMP_TABLE_ID
```

Or

```
SELECT @list = seg_tag 
             + '01' 
             + CASE WHEN LEN(ID_Type) < 10 THEN '0' ELSE '' END + 
             + CAST(LEN(ID_Type) AS varchar)
             + ID_Type  
             + '02'
             + CASE WHEN LEN(IDNumber) < 10 THEN '0' ELSE '' END + 
             + CAST(LEN(IDNumber) AS varchar)
             + IDNumber
FROM #TEMP_TABLE_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT @list = (RIGHT('0'+seg_tag,2)+
            '01'+ 
            RIGHT('0'+CAST(LEN(ID_Type) AS NVARCHAR),2)+
            RIGHT('0'+ID_Type,2)+
            '02'+
            RIGHT('0'+CAST(LEN(IDNumber) AS NVARCHAR),2)+
            RIGHT('0'+IDNumber,2))
FROM #TEMP_TABLE_ID
```

Comment: FOR WHICH COLUMN YOU NEED ZERO

Comment: As you can see, this list is a string made of different values,among those values I'm trying to print the field length(s).Now, those length values are the ones I want to begin with zero if and only if it is a single digit value.You can look at the example again.

Comment: see put 0 before column value and select right 2 charecter.if your value is 2 then make it 02 and select right('02',2) it will be 02 and if value i like 25 then 025 and value will be select right(025,2) 25 only.put 0 and use right function of sql

Comment: What do you mean by *not working*? this should return a string like 
`04010509020407`. if you want it as separate values, you should not concatenate them with `+`

Comment: My original query will return a string like PN03015paras026narang
PN03(i.e value of seg_tag)01(hard coded)5(length of id_type)paras(value of id_type)02(hard code)6(length of IDNumber)narang(value of IDNumber)
Now all I want is, the lengths i.e 5 & 6 to be 05 and 06.